# There is a game to find a random number base on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to generate a random number (1,100), however, the random number is bigger than the user idea changes the range of random EX: computer random =36 but users answer is 87 so tell the computer my answer is bigger than your guess, the computer change its range (36,100) and vice versa.
this program runs just one time and doesn't repeat asking for select more randomly.
Thank you so much

```py
from random import randint
a = int(1)
b = int(100)`enter code here`
guess = randint(a,b)
print(guess)
answer = input ("your idea:")

while answer != "done":
    if answer == "big":
        a = int(guess)
        guess = randint(a,100)
        print(guess)
    if answer == "small":
        b = int(guess)
        guess = randint(1, b)
        print(guess)

    else:
        answer == "done"
        print("your guess number ", guess, "is right")

    break
```

Comment: You might have forgotten to ask a question...

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal _"this program runs just one time and doesn't repeat asking for select more randomly. "_

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

```
else:
    answer == "done"
    print("your guess number ", guess, "is right")

break
```

The break is indented outside the else. So it'll break regardless of the value of the answer. Just indent the break inside the else and it'll be fine